# Paging a partial view only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view which calls two partial views.

_partialView is a PagedList, _viewHeader has radio button to select various filters. I need to be able to page through _partialView without reloading  _viewHeader.

This works but the _viewHeader view gets reloaded when I click the pager button and the radio buttons get set to default values.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { currentFilter = @ViewBag.CurrentFilter, page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() {InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "partial" }))
```

If I do this when the page button is clicked just the _partialView gets loaded without the header and layout (otherwise it works)

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("_partialView", new { currentFilter = @ViewBag.CurrentFilter, page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() {InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "partial" }))
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, any suggestions?

This is my Index.cshtml view.

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyProject.Models.Kaizen>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;


@*<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    ViewBag.AssignedTo = "";
}


@Html.Partial("_viewHeader")
<div id="partial">
   @Html.Action("_partialView", "Home")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who is interested I managed to figure out how to do this using JQuery.

```
//Page button clicked
        $(function(){
            $('#partial').on('click', 'a', function () {
                //alert('Click Detected');
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                //alert(url);
                $('#partial').load(url);
                return false;
            })
        })
```

This pages the _partialView without affecting the _ViewHeader.